# trouble with string to date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Greetings StackWarriors....

I am in need of some help.

I have this SQL Select statement:

```
SELECT GEOID, cast(LEFT(PP.PurchaseDate,4) + RIGHT(Left(PP.PurchaseDate,6),2) as integer) AS Month 
FROM PropertyParametersNew PP
join PropertyTracts PT on PP.ParcelID = PT.PARCELID
WHERE
    PP.PurchaseDate >0
    and convert(datetime, PP.PurchaseDate, 112)>= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,getdate())
```

The intent in this query is trying to get GEOID, and the year/month associated in the PurchaseDate Column.

and I'm getting this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I realized that inside that column, I have `yyyymmdd` formatted dates that have 00's in the mm and dd.  Examples include `20130000` and `20120300`.

I am trying to rephrase the sql query to handle those entries.

My owners say that `0000` should reflect `January 1`, and `00` should reflect the 1st of the month.

How can I restructure this SQL statement to reflect this value, so I can get Year/Month combo without the conversion failure?

Thanks.

Comment: To start with, I'd fix my data. Is there any justification to have "20130101" and "20130000" mean the same date, yet keep both as different values?

Comment: may be the problem lies in convert(datetime, PP.PurchaseDate, 112)>= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,convert(datetime, GETDATE(), 112))

Comment: @Amit, unfortunately fixing the data is not optional because in other queries, 20130000 means 20131231.  It would be easier if I could. Lol.  Thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` to fix values in `PurchaseDate`, then simply use fixed field in its place:

(edit made after correct remark by @t-clausen)

```
SELECT GEOID, 
       cast(LEFT(x.PurchaseDate,4) + RIGHT(Left(x.PurchaseDate,6),2) as integer) AS Month 
FROM PropertyParametersNew PP
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(PP.PurchaseDate, 4) = '0000' 
                           THEN LEFT(PP.PurchaseDate, 4) + '0101'
                         WHEN RIGHT(PP.PurchaseDate, 2) = '00'  
                           THEN LEFT(PP.PurchaseDate, 6) + '01'
                         ELSE PurchaseDate
                    END) x(PurchaseDate)
JOIN PropertyTracts PT on PP.ParcelID = PT.PARCELID
WHERE
    PP.PurchaseDate >0
    and convert(datetime, x.PurchaseDate, 112)>= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,getdate())
```

If, for example, `PP.PurchaseDate` is equal to `20130000`, then the above query sets `x.PurchaseDate` equal to `20130101` and uses this value inside `CONVERT` as well as in `SELECT` clause.

For all this to work `PP.PurchaseDate` must be of fixed length (8 characters).

Comment: This is not a good answer. the replace fails on dates like 2015-10-0x and 2009-xx-xx

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes, this is correct. I have rewritten my answer. I tried to take into account the fact that the OP seems to want to reuse 'fixed' value also in the `SELECT` clause of his query.

Answer (score 1):

Best senario would be fixing the data to date second best would be changing your dates to be valid dates as char(8).

But your question is how to write your select.

You should not convert the purchase date to datetime, you should go the other way and convert the getdate() to char(8). This will give you a better performance. Then there is the issue of the varchar being 20130000. You can compensate by subtracting 1 from the date and ask for a greater value instead of greater equal.

The answer is quite simple and improves performance because you don't have a conversion on your column:

```
WHERE 
  PP.PurchaseDate >0
  and PP.PurchaseDate >
    CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(MONTH,-1,getdate())-1, 112)
```